# Understanding TextInputFormat in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am from Mainframes background and trying to understand different input formats in Hadoop. Can anyone please explain the all below three input formats:

– TextInputFormat
- KeyValueInputFormat
- SequenceFileInputFormat

Answer (score 0):

**TextInputFormat:** It reads lines of text files and provides the offset of the line as key to the Mapper and actual line as Value to the mapper.

The TextInputFormat works as An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. Keys are the position in the file, and values are the line of text..

**KeyValueTextInputFormat(old KeyValueInputFormat):** This format also treats each line of input as a separate record. Everything up to the first tab character is sent as key to the Mapper and the remainder of the line is sent as value to the mapper.

While the TextInputFormat treats the entire line as the value, the KeyValueInputFormat breaks the line itself into the key and value by searching for a tab character.

**SequenceFileInputFormat:** reads special binary files that are specific to Hadoop. These files include many features designed to allow data to be rapidly read into Hadoop mappers.

Sequence files are block-compressed and provide direct serialization and deserialization of several arbitrary data types (not just text). Sequence files can be generated as the output of other MapReduce tasks and are an efficient intermediate representation for data that is passing from one MapReduce job to anther.